# Functions 1.14 Execution Coordinates and Scripting Help with Execute

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have the following code (in Java Version ) that is designed to print out a warning message when the player (who doesn't have a team listed) enters the radius of 70 blocks of the command block. I have attempted instead to cast the field around an armor stand nearby, but neither methods work. It is on a server (that I run and host, commandblocks have been enabled). In order to run the function, I just do function funcs:temple/playerdef. Have a look at the code below.

```
execute at @s[type=minecraft:armor_stand, tag=here] run execute as @a[tag=!mortal, team=!AthenaKnights, team=!NyxNova, distance=..70] run tellraw @s {"text":"You have entered holy land without permission! May curses come down upon you!", "color":"dark_red"}
execute as @a[team=!AthenaKnights, team=!NyxNova, distance=..70] run tag @s add mortal
execute at @s[tag=mortal, distance=..70] run function funcs:fx/flamepillar
effect give @s[tag=mortal, distance=..70] minecraft:blindness 5 5 true
effect give @s[tag=mortal, distance=..70] minecraft:levitation 5 140 true
execute as @a[tag=mortal, distance=71..] run tellraw @s {"text":"Your curses have been lifted for exiting the holy land.", "color":"green"}
```

The idea is, when they leave the radius, the effects and tag should get removed. But for some reason it is not executing at all when I execute it through a repeat commandblock.

Comment: Note that the funcs:fx/flamepillar function works perfectly, as I have tested that separately.

Comment: Can you reduce it to the minimum example, please? You have quite a lot of things there that are probably not essential for this problem and debugging all of this is way more work than finding the problem in a smaller example.

Comment: @FabianRöling - I dont know where the error is, because it loads into Minecraft (so therefore no syntax errors) and doesn't provide a runtime error like it would if for example it could not find a player. Im expecting it to be a logical error, but I cannot deduce where. To be clear, the function is designed to tell the player that they have crossed a point in the world (within 70 blocks of the command block) then append a tag to them (to prevent them from getting it spammed to them) then get debuff effects added to them (and particles) and then when they leave, remove the tag and tell them.

Comment: So, what does happen? Does the player stays cursed when they leave the holy land? Does the "you have left" message gets spammed? Does the curse not trigger at all? Something else?

Comment: So, the curse is applied when they enter, the enter message is done once. THen the effects are applied continuously until they leave the zone. Then when they leave the zone the "you have left" message is printed once and all effects are removed. Thats the simplest way I can put it I think.

Comment: just so you know, chaining multiple "executes" is unneeded. ex. in your first command, instead of ``execute at @s[type=minecraft:armor_stand, tag=here] run execute as @a..``, you can shorten it a little with just ``execute at @s[type=minecraft:armor_stand, tag=here] as @a..``. also, check to make sure "always active" is set in your repeating command block (if not, make sure it's being powered). also also, what part specifically is not being executed? does it give the message? check what tags a player has with ``tag <user> list``.